# Create non-standard pandas frequency ("dekads" = 3 periods per month)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series, statsmodels

As `statsmodels.tseries` models require indexes with a given frequency to make forecasts and I need my data to have a non-standard frequency.

Therefore, I want to create a new frequency to assign to a `pandas.DateTimeIndex`.
This a `dekad` frequency where there are 36 periods in a year. Three per month. The first is always on the 10th day of the month, the second the 20th day of the month, and the final is the final day of that month.

The difficulty is that the final day of the month:

1. differs in February depending on whether it's a leap year (28th or 29th)
2. differs depending on the number of days in that month (28, 29, 30, 31)

Ultimately, however, it is a set frequency (3 per month, 36 periods per year).

The reason is that `statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters` models require indexes with a given frequency to make forecasts. When I try to run the `holtwinters` forecast I get the following warning message:

```
/home/tommy/miniconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/base/tsa_model.py:216: ValueWarning: A date index has been provided, but it has no associated frequency information and so will be ignored when e.g. forecasting.
```

## This is what dekad timesteps look like:

```py
from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthEnd

dates = pd.date_range("2000-01-01", "2003-01-01")
_dekads = [d for d in dates if d.day in [10, 20]]
_month_ends = [d + MonthEnd(1) for d in dates if d.day == 10]
dekads = sorted(np.concatenate([_dekads, _month_ends]))
```

I want to be able to assign a dekad frequency to the index

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"y": np.random.random(len(dekads))}, index=dekads)

df.head()
```

```
Out[]:
            y
2000-01-10  0.013236
2000-01-20  0.430563
2000-01-31  0.028183
2000-02-10  0.050080
2000-02-20  0.092100
```

I'd like to be able to assign a "dekad" frequency to the object. How can I create my own dekad frequency?

```py
df.index.freq = "dekad"
```

```
Out[]:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
pandas/_libs/tslibs/offsets.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.offsets._get_offset()

KeyError: 'DEKAD'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
pandas/_libs/tslibs/offsets.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.offsets.to_offset()

pandas/_libs/tslibs/offsets.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.offsets._get_offset()

ValueError: Invalid frequency: DEKAD

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-155-aa7b4737fd5a> in <module>
      7 
      8 df = pd.DataFrame({"y": np.random.random(len(dekads))}, index=dekads)
----> 9 df.index.freq = "dekad"

~/miniconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/extension.py in fset(self, value)
     62 
     63             def fset(self, value):
---> 64                 setattr(self._data, name, value)
     65 
     66             fget.__name__ = name

~/miniconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/datetimelike.py in freq(self, value)
   1090     def freq(self, value):
   1091         if value is not None:
-> 1092             value = to_offset(value)
   1093             self._validate_frequency(self, value)
   1094 

pandas/_libs/tslibs/offsets.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.offsets.to_offset()

pandas/_libs/tslibs/offsets.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.offsets.to_offset()

ValueError: Invalid frequency: dekad
```

# **How can I create a new `freq` object in pandas**

### The purpose of this exercise:

```py
df = pd.read_csv(
    "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/tommylees112/2b1b2dda43d91ea9346a6edaa6788ec8/raw/644af74955ce078d1c4d55a2ffd6a55eeb59bad4/demo_data_SO_02092021.csv"
).astype({"time": "datetime64[ns]"}).set_index("time")

train, test = df.iloc[:-100], df.iloc[-100:]


f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 4))
ax.plot(train, label="train")
ax.plot(test, label="test")
plt.xticks(rotation=70)
plt.legend()
```

[image: Train Test split of Dekad data]

```py
from statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters import SimpleExpSmoothing, ExponentialSmoothing

# set seasonality parameters
m = 36
alpha = 1/(2*m)

model = ExponentialSmoothing(train["vci"],trend="mul").fit()

preds = model.forecast(len(test))
preds.index = test.index

f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 4))
ax.plot(train.index, model.fittedvalues, label="Train Preditions")
ax.plot(test.index, preds, label="Test Preditions")
ax.plot(df.index, df["vci"], ls="--", color="k", alpha=0.6)
plt.xticks(rotation=70)
plt.legend()
```

[image: Model fitting and prediction (on test data)]

This forecast is clearly poor and does not reflect the learned seasonality. I believe this is an issue with the fact that no frequency has been assigned to the datetime index.

If there are alternative methods for achieving these goals then I would be very keen to explore those options. I want to create a new frequency to assign to a `pandas.DateTimeIndex`. The reason is that `statsmodels.tseries` models require indexes with a given frequency to make forecasts.

Answer (score 3):

You could edit the source code and add the rules to define your frequency there but you probably don't want to go that way.

An easy implementation would be to use the existing [custom business day frequency](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#custom-business-days):

```
pd.offsets.CustomBusinessDay(
    holidays=my_holidays,
    weekmask=my_weekdays,
)
```

and define your holiday calendar to be every day except 10, 20 and `is_month_end`[offset aliases docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#offset-aliases)

I guess you want your weekdays to be monday to sunday (to be sure you do not leave out 10th, 20th or `is_month_end`)

```
start_date = '1/1/2023'
end_date = '31/12/2023'
full_calendar = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date)[source](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html)

my_holidays = full_calendar[full_calendar.day != 10] #not the 10th of the month
my_holidays = my_holidays[my_holidays.day != 20] #not the 20th of the month
my_holidays = my_holidays[~my_holidays.is_month_end] #not the last day of the month
my_weekdays = = "Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat"
dekad = pd.offsets.CustomBusinessDay(
    holidays=my_holidays,
    weekmask=my_weekdays,
)
```

Now you can use it as a `freq`

```
my_dekad_dates = pd.date_range("2000-01-01", "2003-01-01", freq=dekad)
```